# wierd html returned by libcurl GET

Tags: c++, network-programming, libcurl

I am working on a program that does multiple get requests from kijiji (need to get the html of 50 or so ads at a time for statistics purposes). I would have made a short compilable program but its not possible in this case. I get good results for the first 30-40 requests (the number of good responses varies), then I get the following:

[picture here, too much html junk to post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLhWX.png)
if you run this in chrome it gives a pretty much empty page that reloads infinetly fast. The question is, is the server doing anti bot protection, or is it something else?

Now here is the kicker: After a bunch of bad responses, I get 1-3 good ones at the end. If I reduce the total number of requests from 50 to say 30, then after 15 good respones, I start getting bad responses, and then again, 1-3 good ones at the end to top it off. If I run my code with a breakpoint at the time the request is made, and I manually execute it each time, then everything works no problem. It just won't work if I put it in the for loop.

Im pretty new to this whole network coding thing, but I had my program working pretty nicely with a few requests (5-10 or so) so I decided to give it the beans, but then I ran into this. here is my curl function that does all the curl stuff:

```
extern size_t write_data(void* ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* stream) {

    int written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE*)stream);
    return written;
}

int txt_Upd(string myURL, int destination)
{
    CURL* curl_handle;
    static const char* headerfilename;
    CURLcode res;

    switch (destination){//create different files so we don't have to refresh the same one back and forth

    case 1: {
        headerfilename = "head.txt";
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        headerfilename = "sr.txt";
        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        headerfilename = "aux1.txt";
        break;
    }
    }

    FILE* headerfile;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, myURL.c_str());
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "VZM_Analytix");
    
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    //curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);

    headerfile = fopen(headerfilename, "w");
    if (headerfile == NULL) {
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);
        return 2;
    }
   
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, headerfile);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
    fclose(headerfile);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

        return res;
}
```

any ideas apprecieated!

Comment: You write data to the header file. Is it your issue?

Comment: @273K I write only to the header file... I removed the body file code as that was a bit misleading. The header file sometimes contains good html which I can later use, but then it starts having the junky html after 30-40 good ones.

Answer (score 0):

Well, adding a Sleep() function for 2 seconds did the trick. I know its a hacky bandaid fix, but a fix nonetheless. I don't really care how long it takes because this bit of the program is supposed to run in the background when im not using my computer, so it can plug away all it wants.